# Could there be an 'invisible' "should" in this sentence? 携帯番号交換しとくんだったな

Tags: subsidiary-verbs, no-da

> 携帯番号交換しとくんだったな。。。

The sentence means "We have interchanged phone numbers in advance."
This makes no sense with the story unless I add "should" before the "have". So could ~teoku's meaning also include "should" ("should prepare in advance") in casual speech, or something like that, which could have this sentence make more sense for me?

Comment: Who told you it means "We have interchanged phone numbers in advance." in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct.

> 「[携帯番号交換]{けいたいばんごうこうかん}しとくんだったな。。。」

means that the persons involved ***DID NOT*** exchange cellphone numbers.

「しとくんだったな」＝「しておくんだったな」 = "should have ~~ed"

***「～～しておくんだった」, which is used idiomatically, expresses one's retrospective regret of not having done ~~.***  In this sense, one could call it "invisible" as it is all idiomatic instead of any part of the phrase literally meaning "should".

The "visible-'should'" versions are:

「～～しとく**べき**だった」 and 「～～しておく**べき**だった」

Thus, the sentence in question means:

> "We/You/They should have exchanged cellphone numbers."

Comment: An alternative translation would be "We *were supposed to* exchange cellphone numbers".